# Is python-numpy-dev a package that is distributed to Linux Distros?

Tags: numpy

Is or was there ever a 'python-numpy-dev' package for Ubuntu or other Linux distros?

I'm trying to get some software compiling/running that according to the author links to the NumPy headers and he's pointing to that package. Google has some scant references to it out there but I've struck out trying to find it, let alone install it. So just wondering if I'm on a wild goose chase here. The code is from 2016 too so I'm hoping to find an early version (~NumPy 1.6.2) to match an older version of SciPy (~0.17).

I've tried using pip and apt-get for variants of 'python-numpy-dev' and 'numpy-dev' without any luck.

Comment: He may have been using a pre-release version of numpy, using some feature waa new at the time.  But by now that version will be old.  You might have try that code with up to date `numpy` and `scipy`, and correct any bugs, most like deprications. Using old out of date code  requires some degree of expertise.

Comment: Yea, that could be it. He was claiming it needed the header files similar to python-dev. There's just enough hits on Google to suggest it is or was at thing, I just can't find anything official or current.